# Wireless mouse not working in 14.04

Tags: wireless, 14.04, usb, mouse

I have a HP X3500 Wireless mouse. Ubuntu 14.04
My problem is, that the mouse isn't responding.

if I issue `lsusb` -

```
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 3938:1031  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b1c1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd    
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 04b3:310b IBM Corp. Red Wheel Mouse    
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub    
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub    
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e00d Foxconn / Hon Hai Broadcom Bluetooth 2.1 Device    
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub    
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

(red wheel mouse is a wired mouse that I am using and when I unplug dongle the Bus 002 Device 010 disappears)
 . 
Things I have tried so far:

- Trying it in each USB port: no effect
- Trying it on an other computer: working
- Changing batteries: no effect

Output of `modprobe -r usbhid` is:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:769 kmod_module_remove_module() could not remove 'usbhid': Operation not permitted
```

Comment: I just had this problem and rebooting fixed it. Have you tried the mouse with a different OS but on the same computer? I know this may seem like too much work, but its still great for diagnoses

Comment: "lsusb -v | grep -E '\<(Bus|iProduct|bDeviceClass|bDeviceProtocol)' 2>/dev/null" , without quotes. then make a udev rule of the device just like we do with adb and android when the phone is not recognised.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did and not sure how, but it worked:

1. Restarted the system.
2. Connected a wired usb (my phone) to port.
3. lsusb - recognosed it.
4. unpluged phone and connected the mouse.
5. Ran lsusb again. mouse recognised and working again.

Comment: Mine worked when I followed this in my HP Envy X360.

Answer (score -1):

In order for you to use modprobe, you will need to be either the root user or use sudo.

so..

```
sudo modprobe -r usbhid
```